# What document to provide Google for french tax residency justification on the Play Store

Tags: google-play, tax

Google asks us to prove our French tax residence on the Play Store in order to be able to sell one of our applications.

We have been trying for several weeks to get approval from Google on this subject but without success. All documents we send are refused.

What document did you provide to Google in order to have your tax residence validated?

We have currently sent:

An official certificate of tax residence received from the taxe service (in FR and EN)
Our "memento fiscal"
Our Kbis
The company's registration documents (including the VAT number, siren, siret, all tax codes, date of creation, duration of the company, address of the head office, etc.)
Thanks for your help, Google is starting to drive us crazy...

Comment: Exact same issue here. I tried the same documents and all got rejected. They told me they need an english only document but I doubt the french tax services provide this kind of document because they already provide a french and english document.

Comment: Have you succeeded to prove your french tax residency?